# Excel VBA Scrape HTML table for text

Tags: html, vba, excel, getelementbyid

Alright,

I've spent hours searching how to grab text from a table and for the life of me I havn't come across a method that worked in my case.

Here is a sample of the HTML that Im trying to get information from

```
<table class="empDetailCard foldable unfolded">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" class="title">
            <span class="fold-control">full name</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold-row">
        <td>
            <div class="badgePhoto reg">
    <img class="photo " src="removed" />
</div>
</td>
        <td>
           <span class="line">
               <span class="section-title">Employee Info</span>
           </span>
           <div class="employeeInfo">
               <div>
                   <span class="line">
                       <span class="row-label">Login</span>
                       mylogin</span>
                   <span class="line">
                       <span class="row-label">Empl ID</span>
                       1234567</span>
                   <span class="line">
                       <span class="row-label">Badge</span>
                       1234567</span>
                   <span class="line">
                       <span class="row-label">Dept ID</span>
                       1234567</span>
                   <span class="line">
                       <span class="row-label">Location</span>
                       1234567
                       </span>
                   <span class="line">
                       <span class="row-label">Manager</span>
                       <a href="removed" 
                    title="">John, Smith</a>
                    </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried to grab "mylogin" from the Login table using GetElementByID, GetElementByName, and even regex but I've had no luck.

```
Function IdtoLogin(empID As String)
     Dim H As Object, html As Object, objResult As Object
     Set H = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
     H.Open "GET", "myurl" & empID
     H.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
     H.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
     H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
     H.send

     Set html = New HTMLDocument
     html.Body.innerHTML = H.ResponseText
     Set objResult = html.GetElementById("Login")
     IdtoLogin = objResult.innerHTML

End Function
```

The response returns the correct HTML with the login information but it fails to get the element ID and throws a "runtime error 91". If someone could point out the obvious for me thatd be great because Im going crazy.

Comment: There are no id's in your posted html.

Comment: this has an ID ... `<div id="mainbar">`

Comment: you have to do `getelementsbyClassName` then compare `innertext` to "Login"

Comment: I've tried getelementsbyclassname but it throws a runtime error 438

Comment: I've updated the main post to show more of the HTML from the page Im trying to get information from.

Comment: Did you use the `(0)` at the end of the `getelementsbyclassname` call?  Or whatever number it is in the page?

Answer (score 1):

Try a CSS selector

```
html.querySelector("div.employeeInfo span")
```

The info you want maybe part of outerHTML for example. By using singular `querySelector` you get the first node match which, in the HTML shown, is `mylogin`:

[image: CSS query]